# How to get selected drop down values from Controller MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

The Following is the View :

```
 <div class="editor-label">
        Select Currency :
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("CurrencyId", new SelectList(ViewBag.CurrencyId, "Value", "Text"))
 </div><div class="editor-label">
         Select GameType :
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
           @Html.DropDownList("GameTypeId", new SelectList(ViewBag.GameTypeId, "Value", "Text"), new { style = "width:100px" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.GameTypeId)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
          Select Category :
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
          @Html.DropDownList("CategoryByGameType", Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), "Select Category")
          @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CategoryId)
        </div>
```

The following is Controller:-

```
 public ActionResult Create()
        {
            List<Currency> objCurrency = new List<Currency>();
            objCurrency = db.Currencies.ToList();
            List<SelectListItem> listItems = new List<SelectListItem>();
            listItems.Add(new SelectListItem()
            {
                Value = "0",
                Text = "Select Currency"
            });
            foreach (Currency item_Currency in objCurrency)
            {
                listItems.Add(new SelectListItem()
                {
                    Value = item_Currency.CurrencyId.ToString(),
                    Text = item_Currency.CurrencyName
                });
            }
            ViewBag.CurrencyId = new SelectList(listItems, "Value", "Text");

            List<GameType> objgametype = objGameByGameType.GetDistinctGameTypeID();
            List<SelectListItem> listItems_1 = new List<SelectListItem>();
            listItems_1.Add(new SelectListItem()
            {
                Value = "0",
                Text = "Select Game Type"
            });
            foreach (GameType item_GameType in objgametype)
            {
                listItems_1.Add(new SelectListItem()
                {
                    Value = item_GameType.GameTypeId.ToString(),
                    Text = item_GameType.GameTypeName
                });
            }
            ViewBag.GameTypeId = new SelectList(listItems_1, "Value", "Text");


            return View();
        }
```

The following is my  Jquery for i am using Casceding Dropdown

```
$(function () {
            $("#GameTypeId").change(function () {
                var theatres = "";
                var gametype = "";
                var mytestvar = "";
                var gametypeid = $(this).val();

            mytestvar += "<option value= -1 >Select Category</option>";
            $.getJSON("@Url.Action("GetCategoryByGameType", "GameCombination")?gametypeid=" + gametypeid, function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (index, gametype) {
                  //  alert("<option value='" + gametype.Value + "'>" + gametype.Text + "</option>");
                    mytestvar += "<option value='" + gametype.Value + "'>" + gametype.Text + "</option>";
                });
                //alert(mytestvar);
                $("#CategoryByGameType").html(mytestvar);
                $("#GamebyCategory").html("<option value=0>Select Game</option>");
                $("#LimitVariantByGameByGameType").html("<option value=0>Select Limit Variant</option>");
                $("#StakeCategory").html("<option value=0>Select Stake Category</option>");
                $("#StakeBuyInByStakeCategory").html("<option value=0>Select Stake Buy In By Stake Category</option>");
      });

    });
    });
```

While submit data i am not able to get back the dropdown value if Error come on creation

Comment: Ok, my first note: because you separated the view and the javascript code, I suspect that the JS is in a separate file. In this case this is not working: `("@Url.Action("GetCategoryByGameType", "GameCombination")`
You cannot use the MVC helper methods in a JS file, you have to specify the URL explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Echo of what Andras said, you can't use razor syntax in a .js file if that's happening.

Also you should get familiar with your debugging tools, what browser are you using? Most have a nice set of developer tools (some have them built in) where you can inspect the page and the request sent out when you submit the form.

You could interactively use jquery in the console of your browser to look around also.

You don't show your post create method, perhaps it is related to that code?

Answer (score 0):

This should give you an idea of what you can do.

I would suggest that you move the ajax into its own function and the `$.each` into its own function and call the `$.each` function out of the ajax function and the ajax function out of the main function.

```
$(function () {
    $("#GameTypeId").change(function () {
        var theatres = "";
        var gametype = "";
        var mytestvar = "";
        var gametypeid = $(this).val();

        mytestvar += "<option value= -1 >Select Category</option>";

        $.ajax({
            url: '/GameCombination/GetCategoryByGameType',
            type: 'GET',
            data: { "gametypeid": gametypeid},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (index, gametype) {
                    //  alert("<option value='" + gametype.Value + "'>" + gametype.Text + "</option>");
                    mytestvar += "<option value='" + gametype.Value + "'>" + gametype.Text + "</option>";
                });
                //alert(mytestvar);
                $("#CategoryByGameType").html(mytestvar);
                $("#GamebyCategory").html("<option value=0>Select Game</option>");
                $("#LimitVariantByGameByGameType").html("<option value=0>Select Limit Variant</option>");
                $("#StakeCategory").html("<option value=0>Select Stake Category</option>");
                $("#StakeBuyInByStakeCategory").html("<option value=0>Select Stake Buy In By Stake Category</option>");
            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert(error.toString());
            }
        }); 

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a object for `dropdownlist` in View.cs and then assign the value. After that when u try to get the `dropdown` values u have to use the ViewBag title object name and then the dropdownlist value.

Below code specifies for the radiobutton. You can alter it for dropdown

```
@model MVC_Compiler.Models.UserProgram
@{
ViewBag.Title = "UserProgram";
}
<table style="background-color: #FBF9EF;">
            <colgroup>
                <col style="width: 20%;">
                <col style="width: 80%;">
            </colgroup>
            <tr>
                <td style="vertical-align: text-top">
                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(up => up.Language, "C")C<br />
                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(up => up.Language, "C++")C++<br />
                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(up => up.Language, "C#")C#<br />
                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(up => up.Language, "VB")VB<br />
                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(up => up.Language, "Java")Java<br />
                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(up => up.Language, "Perl")Perl<br />
                    @Html.HiddenFor(up => up.Language, new { @id = "Select_Language" })
                    @Html.HiddenFor(up => up.UserName, new { @id = "UserName" })
                </td>
```

Then in Models you can get the radio button value by following way:

```
userProgram.Language
```

where userProgram is ViewBag Title.